# how can i find channel by name which includes emoji Discord?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, commando

i used `` const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === `welcome`); `` code to get simple channel name which says welcome but when the same channel includes emojis `welcome`
how do i find any channel which is inside emoji `welcome` this or any other emoji.

`` const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === `welcome`);
// some code here 
 channel.send(`See you once again ${member}!`, attachment); ``

something like this but does not work i tried

`const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === welcome);`
my server looks like this [my server with channel name and emojis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypMwZ.png)

my complete code is like this -

```
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === `welcome`);
    if (!channel) return;
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper.jpg');
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Slightly smaller text placed above the member's display name
    ctx.font = '28px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText('Welcome to the server,', canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 3.5);

    // Add an exclamation point here and below
    ctx.font = applyText(canvas, `${member.displayName}!`);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText(`${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.8);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();

    const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL);
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

    const attachment = new Discord.Attachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');

    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`, attachment);
```

lets say i need to find levels channel like in above image the emojis will change but the name will be there so how can i do that
this is the data i am trying to add
**EDIT**
name is welcome but when i add emoji the name changes

```
'554141970130403338' => TextChannel {
    type: 'text',
    deleted: false,
    id: '554141970130403338',
     name: '≡ƒô£welcome≡ƒô£',
    position: 0,
    parentID: '566212268208029697',
    permissionOverwrites: Collection [Map] {
      '159985870458322944' => [PermissionOverwrites],
      '417208237142573056' => [PermissionOverwrites],
      '487733104652582920' => [PermissionOverwrites]
    },
    topic: '',
    nsfw: false,
    lastMessageID: '628112146806472715',
    lastPinTimestamp: null,
    rateLimitPerUser: 0,
    guild: Guild {
      members: [Collection [Map]],
      channels: [Circular],
      roles: [Collection [Map]],
      presences: [Collection [Map]],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      id: '417208237142573056',
      name: 'ETHYT Gaming',
      icon: '081568475c94dd5724dafc2547a0261c',
      splash: null,
      region: 'india',
      memberCount: 86,
      large: false,
      features: [],
      applicationID: null,
      afkTimeout: 3600,
      afkChannelID: '440842028713115648',
      systemChannelID: null,
      embedEnabled: undefined,
      verificationLevel: 0,
      explicitContentFilter: 0,
      mfaLevel: 0,
      joinedTimestamp: 1557471391163,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
      ownerID: '348832732647784460',
      _rawVoiceStates: [Collection [Map]],
      emojis: [Collection [Map]]
    },
    messages: Collection [Map] { '628112146806472715' => [Message] },
    _typing: Map {}
  }
```

when i got the output in notepad i can see the welcome written but what before and after it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) will be of great use to you. Instead of comparing the whole string, it'll search for your substring anywhere within it.

```js
const channelName = 'welcome';
console.log(channelName.includes('welcome'));
```

Comment: sir i added the data which i am trying to add plz look into it

Comment: @Root Android You can find the channel using `String.includes()` within your predicate function. `...channels.find(ch => ch.name.includes('welcome'))`. Is this not what you're asking?

Comment: thanks now i understood i learning and this is my self project i took to make a full functional discord bot with multiple apis and features so i will be needing ur help in near feature

Answer (score 0):

You can use`const channel = member.guild.channels.get('554141970130403338');` with '554141970130403338' the channel id.

Comment: hay now i know that too but the main reason is it will send to multiple servers so i need to get the id here u inputted the id so means it will send to that servers channel only not others :(